# fs.watch auto reload commands on discord bot

Tags: node.js, fs, discord.js

I have been working on my Discord Bot `Rxiqi` and I've been wanting auto-reload commands when the file has changed... my code is

```
var folder = "./commands/";
fs.watch(folder, { encoding: 'UTF-8' }, (eventType, filename) => {
    if (eventType ==="change") {
        console.log(`Updating Command: ${folder+filename}`)
        delete require.cache[require.resolve(folder+filename)];
        client.commands.delete(folder+filename);
        const props = require(filename);
        client.commands.set(folder+filename,props);
    }
});
```

But I keep getting this console output:

```
Updating Command: ./commands/adverts.js
Error: Cannot find module './commands/adverts.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.resolve (internal/module.js:18:19)
    at FSWatcher.fs.watch (E:\BotDevelopment\Rxiqi\status\ready.js:62:38)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at FSWatcher.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at FSEvent.FSWatcher._handle.onchange (fs.js:1364:12)
Updating Command: ./commands/adverts.js
Error: Cannot find module './commands/adverts.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.resolve (internal/module.js:18:19)
    at FSWatcher.fs.watch (E:\BotDevelopment\Rxiqi\status\ready.js:62:38)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at FSWatcher.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at FSEvent.FSWatcher._handle.onchange (fs.js:1364:12)
```

Any help is very much appreciated :)

Comment: `const props = require(filename);` line should be `const props = require(folder + filename);` , possibly

Comment: Nope, that still returns the exact same error stack. thanks for trying tho :)

Answer (score 0):

What OS are you on? If you're on windows there is a problem as your '/' will not work

Comment: Windows 10, but I don't have this issue with my Reload Command, which is using the same layout.